# ReplacePart inside For loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to replace the last column of the following expression (`mat`) by doing

```
mat = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}};
For[q = 1, q < 3, q +=1,
  If[mat[[q, 2]] < 3, ReplacePart[mat, {q, 2} -> -1], ReplacePart[mat, {q, 2} -> 1]];]
```

So I expect to get

```
mat = {{1, -1}, {1, 1}}
```

But nothing changes.
Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Ivan, _Mathematica_ questions should be asked on this site. Meta (where you originally asked this) is only for questions and discussions about _this site_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that you did not assign the replaced values back to the matrix `mat` (just add `mat = ReplacePart[...]` in your `For` loop). `ReplacePart` does not work like `AppendTo`, so you'll have to explicitly overwrite `mat`.

The longer answer to your question is that `For` loops are almost always an inefficient way to do things in *Mathematica*. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/5) for a beginner's quick-guide. An alternative way of doing the same thing:

```
mat = mat /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ} :> {a, If[b < 3, -1, 1]}
(* {{1, -1}, {1, 1}} *)
```

You can even use `ReplacePart` in a single line:

```
mat = ReplacePart[mat, {i_, 2} :> If[mat[[i, 2]] < 3, -1, 1]]
```